# debugging in STS and Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, sts

Is debugging an application in STS and eclipse similar? If different can U mention those parts. I have tried to learn about debugging in STS but the resources are limited.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you refer to "STS", you are referring to "Spring Tool Suite".  The Spring Tool Suite is simply a set of Eclipse plugins.  You can also install Spring Tool Suite with a separate installer, but it's still just Eclipse with a set of plugins.

So, addressing the main question, debugging an application in STS and Eclipse are more than similar. They are identical.

You should be searching for information about debugging application in Eclipse.